# How to get data from NXOAuth2Request response

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, oauth2client

I'm writing my first iOS app. It includes API calls through OAuth2Client.

The problem is when calling the AdvAPI getUser function. A GET request is made through NXOAuth2Request which deals with the response data in responseHandler and variable result is set to an NSDictionary. The result however is not accessible outside the XOAuth2Request function. How can I get the result and return it from getUser?

Thanks!

```
import Foundation

class AdvAPI {
var store : NXOAuth2AccountStore
var account : NXOAuth2Account?

init(){
    self.store = NXOAuth2AccountStore.sharedStore() as NXOAuth2AccountStore
    self.store.setClientID(
        "test",
        secret: "test",
        authorizationURL: NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize"),
        tokenURL: NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3000/oauth/token"),
        redirectURL: NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3000/oauth/connect"),
        forAccountType: "AdventureApp"
    )

    self.account = self.store.accountsWithAccountType("AdventureApp")[0]
}


func getUser(parameters : NSDictionary=[String: AnyObject]()) -> NSDictionary {

    NXOAuth2Request.performMethod("GET",
        onResource: NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/me"),
        usingParameters: parameters,
        withAccount: self.account,
        sendProgressHandler: nil,
        responseHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?, responseData: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            var jsonError: NSError
            var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        }
    )
    return result
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The getUser function returns before the NXOAuth2Request is completed and therefore never sets the result variable.

To get around this the only option appears to be to call a callback from within responseHandler when the request is completed as such.

```
 func getUser(parameters : NSDictionary=[String: AnyObject]()) {
    NXOAuth2Request.performMethod("GET",
        onResource: NSURL.URLWithString("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/me"),
        usingParameters: parameters,
        withAccount: self.account,
        sendProgressHandler: nil,
        responseHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse?, responseData: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            var jsonError: NSError
            var result = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
            self.delegate.didReceiveAPIResult(result)
        }
    )
 }
```